# Proving inequality using induction

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Question:

$ Prove\ for\ all\ natural\ n:\ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots +\ \frac{1}{3n+1}>1 $

I know that the base case holds. I.H: Assume it is true for $n = k$. Now I am not sure how to prove it for $n = k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

By the induction assumption we have
$$\frac{1}{k+2}+...+\frac{1}{3k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}+\frac{1}{3k+4}>$$
$$>1-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}+\frac{1}{3k+4}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$1-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}+\frac{1}{3k+4}>1,$$
which is $$\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+4}>\frac{2}{3(k+1)},$$
which is C-S:
$$\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+4}\geq\frac{(1+1)^2}{3k+2+3k+4}=\frac{2}{3(k+1)}.$$

A proof by C-S:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n+k}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n+1}1\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n+1}(n+k)}=\frac{(2n+1)^2}{\frac{(2(n+1)+(2n+1-1)\cdot1)(2n+1)}{2}}=1.$$
Since $\frac{1}{n+1}\neq\frac{1}{n+2}$, the equality does not occur and we are done!

Comment: The last inequality follows immediately from the convexity of $1/x$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I think C-S is nicer, but your way is also nice.

Comment: How did you get $ \frac{1}{3k+2}+\ \frac{1}{3k+3} $

Comment: @Josh Mitkitze We need to substitute $n=k+1$ and we need to prove that $\frac{1}{k+2}+...+\frac{1}{3k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}+\frac{1}{3k+4}>1$ because for $n=k+1$ we have $3n+1=3(k+1)+1=3k+4$.

Comment: Could you please show where you used the induction hypothesis?

Comment: @Josh Mitkitzel $\frac{1}{k+2}+...+\frac{1}{3k+1}>1-\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$, it is $\frac12+\frac13+\frac14>1.$

Assume it is true for $n=k.$

We'll prove for $n=k+1:$

$$\frac{1}{k+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}+\frac{1}{3k+4}=$$
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{k+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3k+1}}_{>1}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+3}+\frac{1}{3k+4}>1 \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{1}{3k+2}+\frac{1}{3k+4}>\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{3k+3} \Rightarrow $$
$$2>0.$$